# Proving that disconnecting edges of a 3-edge-colorable graph are of the same color

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring, graph-connectivity

I'm struggling to prove the following:

> Edges of a connected cubic graph G can be colored with 3 colors in
> such a way that no adjacent edges are of the same color. 2 edges were
> removed from the graph making it disconnected. Proof that those edges
> were of the same color.

I've found an example of a cubic graph with two edges that disconnect it, and tried to color them with different colors and failed to do that, but I'm not sure how to prove that.

[image: example of a graph]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proceed by contradiction. Let $H$ be $G$ after removing the two edges.

Take a connected component $C$ of $H$ and assume $e$ is a removed edge from a vertex $x$ in $C$ to a vertex not in $C$.

Also assume $e$ is blue and the other removed edge is green.

Let the other color be red. Note that the red edges with endings in $C$ form a matching of $C$ so $|C|$ is even.

On the other hand the blue edges with endings in $C$ form a matching of $C\setminus \{x\}$ so $|C|-1$ is even.

A contradiction.

Comment: By $C∖{x}$ do you mean $C - x$ (graph induced by $C∖{x}$)?

Comment: @Ellie yeah, I used the "setminus" latex thingy, which means the same thing :)

Comment: Ok, thank you. Also, great solution!